# How are blind writes recoverable in a transaction schedule?

Tags: transactions

Consider the following schedule -

```
T1     T2

R(A)
W(A)
       R(A)
       W(A)
       Commit
Commit
```

I understand that this schedule is non-recoverable, because if a failure occurs between the two commits, then we can't rollback the operations performed by T2, as they would already have been committed.

But, if we change this schedule to

```
T1     T2

R(A)
W(A)
       R(A)
       W(A)
Commit
       Commit
```

then this becomes recoverable, as if a failure now occurs immediately before T1's commit, then all the operations performed by T1 and T2 can be rolled back, and if a failure occurs between the two commits, then we can roll back only T2's operations and run only T2 separately again.

Now, everywhere that I've read about recoverable schedules, it is written that a recoverable schedule is one where, for each pair of transactions Ti and Tj such that Tj **reads** a data item previously written by Ti, the commit operation of Ti appears before the commit operation of Tj.

So, if we go by this definition, then the following schedule must be recoverable -

```
T1     T2

R(A)
W(A)
       W(A)
       Commit
Commit
```

But, how is this schedule recoverable?
In this case as well, if a failure occurs between the two commits, then we again can't roll back T2's W(A) operation, and if we roll back only T1's operations and run only T1 separately, then the final value that will be reflected in the database will be T1's W(A), when our original intention was to store T2's W(A) in the database.